# Adjust center of the map based on marker position Openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a map in which a moving marker is placed to represent a vehicle. I am using `setCoordinate()` method to move the marker.

I need to set the center of the map to the position of the vehicle marker whenever the marker reaches any one of the four boundaries of map. How do I know that the marker is at the boundary in order to set the center of the map and set the center whenever it is at the boundary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow, I found the answer

```
//calculate the extent of the map

var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
extent = ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');

//compare the values with the marker position 

 if((extent[0]>lon || lon>extent[2])||(extent[1]>lat || lat>extent[3])) {
        //set the center to the marker position 
  map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.transform([lon, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
}
```